# How to change the default name of auto snapshot taken by linstor?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-storage, kubernetes-pvc

I am able to capture the snapshots of resource-definition using below commands
`linstor rd sp pvc-00 AutoSnapshot/RunEvery 15` which captures a snapshot of given resource-definition(pvc-00) after every 15 minutes..

```
 ResourceName  ┊ SnapshotName
 pvc-006       ┊ autoSnap00071
```

the snapshot is by default getting captured with the name autoSnap00071 , is there a way where i can manually provide a name to snapshots?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ghernadi mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/LINBIT/linstor-server/issues/44#issuecomment-451837782)

Currently Linstor does not support any kind of renaming action.
If you really have to do this, you have two options:

- NOT RECOMMENDED: you do it manually by editing the database (NOT
  recommended, as you have to be very careful to update all references
  to the changed name)
- a bit "more" recommended: delete your current database (or perform
  "lostNode" commands for the affected nodes) and recreate using
  migration everything with the new storage pool names.

Note: we do have internal discussions if and how we could provide renaming actions. That means this situation might be easier to resolve in (far) future

This is an Open issue you can follow this [github](https://github.com/LINBIT/linstor-server/issues/44#issuecomment-451837782) link for more feature enhancements.
You can also raise a comment under this link or  else you can raise a new feature request .

Refer to this official [Linstor documentation](https://linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/linstor-guide-1_0-en/) for more information.